# How do I get the PowerBuilder graphicobject for a given HWND handle?

Tags: c++, c, windows, powerbuilder

In my (PowerBuilder) application, I'd like to be able to determine the `graphicobject` object which corresponds to a given window handle.

Simply iterating over the `Control[]` array and comparing the value returned by the `Handle()` function for each of the child controls doesn't work, since not all objects in my application are children of the main window (consider of login dialogs).

Any PowerScript or C/C++ solution would be acceptable.

Is there maybe some window message I could send to window handles, and this message is only understood by PowerBuilder windows, which would the respond with their internal object name, or the like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it a requirement to determine the object from the handle, or do you just want to identify an object, for example to know where the code you need to modify is? I made a tool that does the latter, but it uses object focus, rather than window handles.

---

(added 2010-06-21) For windows that aren't children of the main window you could explicitly check each of these window class names with `isValid()`. Then for each valid window, dig through looking for the handle. This should work as long as you only open one instance of the window class at a time. If you open multiple instances, I think you'll need to add a registration mechanism to the `open` of those windows so the application has a way to access them.

Comment: Unfortunately, the former is the case for me. I need to get the graphicobject (if any) of my PowerBuilder application which corresponds to a given window handle.

Comment: Are you inheriting all of your windows from ancestor classes?

Comment: @Hugh: No, I'm not; I did consider that alternative (and then maintaining a HWND->graphicobject mapping in the 'open' event handler) but unfortunately I cannot use it in my case.

Comment: Is this functionality required in normal use, or is it for testing? Also, what is the constraint against the mapping that Terry suggested? Is maintaining the mapping a problem or is the need to modify all windows unacceptable?

Comment: Oops, sorry for not replying earlier. I don't need this functionality in normal use, I'd like to use it for GUI testing. The tool we use allows to exhibit additional functionality (read: properties or functions) for a given HWND by writing a little plugin which queries for the additional information via toolkit-specific API. In my case, I'm using PBNI to implement such a plugin - I solved most things already, but I lack a good way to identify the PowerBuilder control for a given HWND handle.